# how to get only English language from a column in snowflake table?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having a table that has data which is **scraped** from web. Below is the same image of the data.
[image]

I am trying to filter on the only english language. I am not sure how to do it as I don't find any documentation regarding it.
I am looking for a simple where clause like

`where language is ENGLISH` that can do this trick.

Comment: My idea is to use Google Translator API that returns the Language of a string as well. But this is complex and costly :( lets see what other people suggests. This will be a learning for me as well :)

Comment: There is no function within snowflake that will allow you to do this.

Comment: Indeed, this is not something databases typically provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ASCII code for the first two/three characters in the string & if it falls in the ASCII range of 65 - 122 + some generic characters/numbers/special characters then filter it out